# Wrong result when query has more filters

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (prs:Issue)-[:REPORTED_BY]-(custs) 
MATCH (prs)-[:CLOSED_ON]-(cls:IssueClosedDate) 
MATCH (prs)-[:REPORTED_BY]->(custNode:Customer) 
MATCH (prs)-[:APP_FUN_CAT]-(afc:AppFunCat) 
MATCH (prs)-[:REPORTED_IN]-(release:Release)
WHERE  afc.func STARTS WITH 'WEB'  AND NOT(cls.closedDate = '' ) AND afc.appName STARTS WITH 'SOCKET' 
AND apoc.date.parse(cls.closedDate,'s', 'MM/dd/yyyy') >= apoc.date.parse('01/01/2014','s', 'MM/dd/yyyy') 
AND apoc.date.parse(cls.closedDate,'s', 'MM/dd/yyyy') <= apoc.date.parse('06/13/2017','s', 'MM/dd/yyyy') 
AND  afc.cat IN ["ALL","NEW","SOFTWARE","UNDETERMINED"] 
RETURN prs.prId AS prList, custs.customerName AS customer, afc.cat AS category, cls.closedDate AS prClosedDate, release.relName as releaseName `
```

The above query gives me result shown below:

```
 "prList"  "funName"  "year"  "afc.appName"  "afc.cat"  "cls.closedDate"  
  7371322  "WEB"      "2015"  "SOCKET"       "SOFTWARE"  "4/27/2015"  
  8277662  "WEB"      "2015"  "SOCKET"       "SOFTWARE"  "9/24/2015"  
  7513015  "WEB"      "2015"  "SOCKET"       "SOFTWARE"  "9/24/2015"
```

This result is not correct if I check with data base. It should have given more number of list than this.

It is found that if I remove either of the filter 
    `afc.appName STARTS WITH 'SOCKET'` or 
    `apoc.date.parse(cls.closedDate,'s', 'MM/dd/yyyy') <= apoc.date.parse('06/13/2017','s', 'MM/dd/yyyy')` or
    `fc.cat IN ["ALL","NEW","SOFTWARE","UNDETERMINED"]`

the result I get is correct. So I can say that the database is build properly. Though the above query is showing the three result there are more number of columns.

Is there any limitation from neo4j database that we cannot do this?
Can anybody suggest how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Which version of Neo4j and which version of the Neo4j browser? Also, can you make sure that "Enable multi statement query editor" is not checked in the browser settings? This can sometimes have buggy effects with queries.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I think neo4j version is 3.2.0 community edition. I am opening the  `http://127.0.0.1:7474/browser/` url in chrome browser. In that the neo4j browser is of 3.0.1 version. Where can I see "Enable multi statement query editor" settings..

Comment: That option is in 3.4.x, so that's not in play here. In any case, you'll want to get off of 3.2.0, as .0 releases tend to be buggy with the debut of all new features. At the very least, get to the latest patch release along the 3.2.x line, but if you can, upgrade to the latest 3.4.x version.

Comment: Can you also share the results you expect with the results that you got for the "correct" and the "wrong" cypher? It is also possible you are overlooking a minor detail, and the results of all the queries are correct, but we can't validate that with the limited info given. If you can reproduce+share via http://console.neo4j.org, that would be tremendously helpful.

Comment: @InverseFalcon thanks for help. It had given the pointer to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by `InverseFalcon` in comment, version might be the issue. We updated the version as mention below:

```
Neo4j Browser version: 3.0.1 to 3.2.8 
Neo4j Server version: 3.2.0 to 3.4.8 (community) 
apoc-3.2.3.5-all.exe to apoc-3.4.0.3-all.exe
```

Now all the filters are working good. Problem is solved.